# Can anyone help figure out why this graph won't plot in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm trying to plot the following Fejer's Kernel:

`((sin(7x/2)^2)/(sin(x/2)^2))*(1/16)`.

Below is the following code that ive tried but for some reason I keep getting errors. Can anyone tell me why this isnt working and help me plot this in Tikz ? It would be massively appreciated!

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=88mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style = {->},
    axis on top,
    trig format=rad,
    xmin=-10.5,  xmax=10.5,
    xtick={-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,...,10},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt},
    xlabel={$x$},   x label style={anchor=west},
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=1.1,
    ylabel={$y$},   y label style={anchor=south},
    domain=-10:10, samples=200
            ]
\addplot [thick,black!80] {((sin(7x/2)^2)/(sin(x/2)^2))*(1/16)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

thanks in advance!

Also apologies for setting out my code poorly in this question. I've seen other people present it very nicely but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it is better to provide a complete test file that people can run rather than just a fragment, also unrelated to any error never put a figure enviornment inside center (the `center` will add vertical space at that point even if the figure floats to a differnt page)

Comment: I can't test right now but PGF doesn't understand `7x/2`, you must write `7*x/2`.

Comment: @SandyG yes, that is the only error in code. However, it gives an incorrect graph even with `samples=1000` Check with Wolfam Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28sin%287*x%2F2%29%5E2%29%2F%28sin%28x%2F2%29%29%5E2%29*%281%2F14%29*1%2Fpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (corrections in function to plot!):

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=88mm,
                axis lines=middle,
                axis line style = {->},
                axis on top,
                trig format=rad,
                xmin=-10.5,  xmax=10.5,
                xtick={-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,...,10},
                tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt},
                xlabel={$x$},   x label style={anchor=west},
                ymin=-0.5,  ymax=1.1,
                ylabel={$y$},   y label style={anchor=south},
                domain=-10:10, samples=200
                ]
                \addplot[thick,black!80] {((sin(7*x/2)^2)/(sin(x/2))^2)*(1/14)*1/pi};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!!